# Binary search tree unique remove method

Tags: c++

```
template <typename Comparable>
void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::remove(BinaryNode *&t)
{
    //Add you code here
    int random = rand() % 100 + 1;

    if(t == nullptr){
        return; //item not found, do nothing. 
    }else if(t->left != nullptr && t->right == nullptr){
        t->element = findMax(t->left)->element;
        remove (t->left);
    }else if(t->right != nullptr && t->left == nullptr){
        t->element = findMin(t->right)->element;
        remove (t->right);
    }else if(t->left != nullptr && t->right != nullptr){
        // int random = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(random % 2 == 0)
            t->element = findMax(t->left)->element;
            remove (t->left);
        if(random % 2 != 0)   
            t->element = findMin(t->right)->element;
            remove (t->right);
    }
}
```

I am writing a remove() method for a BST. So to walk through the code. If t is a nullptr, we do nothing. If the t->left node is not null and t->right is null then we remove the maximum node of the left subtree. If t->left is null and t->right is not null then we remove the minimum node of the right subtree. if both t->left and t->right are not null then we assign a random integer. If the remainder of random % 2 is 0 then we delete the maximum node of the left subtree. If it is 1 then we remove the minimum node of the right subtree.

The output for my code:

```
The built binary search tree (BST) is (preorder traversal):
50 30 20 15 25 40 35 45 70 60 55 65 80 75 85 

The updated binary search tree (BST) is (preorder traversal):
45 35 15 15 25 35 35 45 65 55 55 65 85 75 85 

The updated binary search tree (BST) is (preorder traversal):
55 35 15 15 25 45 35 45 65 55 55 65 90 78 78 90 90 

The updated binary search tree (BST) is (preorder traversal):
45 26 26 10 10 26 26 35 35 45 65 65 55 65 90 78 78 90 90
```

clearly it is not doing what it is suppossed to so I was seeing if I can get some advice on this. Thanks.

Comment: When in your algorithm do you actually remove a node (as opposed to deferring removal to the next step)?

Comment: You don't seem to be actually searching for the value. You assume that if it's not nullpointer, you've found it.

Comment: @sweenish Was searching for a value supposed to be part of the process? It looked to me like an attempt to remove a random leaf from the tree. :innocent:

Comment: @JaMiT I think not removing the node is the problem as well. According to the output it seems like it is getting replaced..

Comment: It's possible that the signature implies a search was run already. However, the text description does make it sound like it's removing whatever it feels like, if it had actual code for removing.

Comment: @gettingthere24 *"I think not removing the node is the problem as well."* -- if you cannot point to where your algorithm does the removal, then fix your algorithm before fixing your code. You have a good step-by-step description of your algorithm. Draw a tree on a piece of paper (or electronic substitute -- but keep it a drawing), then go through the steps manually. See where your algorithm goes off track.

Comment: @sweenish its searching for the max of left subtree if (t->left !=NULL && t->right ==NULL)and removing it.  or min of right subtree if(t_right !=NULL && t->left ==NULL). If neither t->left or t->right is null than we execute according to the remainder of random.

Comment: The indentation of your `if(random % 2 == 0)` statement and its inverse (which should be using `else` instead does not match the actual behavior (you have no brackets to enclose multiple statements)

Comment: Answered my question

Comment: I think my problem was not using recursion properly. I got a better grasp of it now.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
template <typename Comparable>
void BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::remove(BinaryNode *&t)
{
    //Add you code here
    int random = rand() % 100 + 1;
    //BinaryNode *oldNode;

    if(t == nullptr){
        return; //item not found, do nothing. 
    }else if(t->left != nullptr && t->right == nullptr){
        remove(t->left);
    }else if(t->right != nullptr && t->left == nullptr){
        remove(t->right);
    }else if(t->left != nullptr && t->right != nullptr){
        // int random = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(random % 2 == 0){
            remove(t->left);
        }else{
            remove(t->right);
        }
    }else{
        BinaryNode *oldNode = t;
        t = (t->left != nullptr) ? t->left : t->right;
        delete oldNode;
    }
}
```

Updated output:

```
The built binary search tree (BST) is (preorder traversal):
50 30 20 15 25 40 35 45 70 60 55 65 80 75 85 

The updated binary search tree (BST) is (preorder traversal):
50 30 20 15 25 40 45 70 60 55 65 80 75 85 

The updated binary search tree (BST) is (preorder traversal):
50 30 20 40 45 70 60 55 65 80 75 78 85 90 

The updated binary search tree (BST) is (preorder traversal):
50 30 20 10 26 40 45 70 60 65 80 75 78 85
```